# Codename One Database print range of rows

Tags: database, selection, codenameone

I am using Codename One to get data from a database and display it in a table.

This is functioning quite well, and now I am trying to add a feature that limits the number of items that are shown in the table. To get there, I want to retrieve a selected number of columns from the database .

Unfortunately, common java sql operations do not seem to work. Below is what I have so far. All approaches don't throw any errors, but also also don't display the desired range or ranges. Another way to obtain a selection would probably be an ArrayList, but I would very much like to stick with a direct approach, since this appears to be relatively easy and elegant solution.

```
    db = display.getInstance().openOrCreate("MyDB.db");
    db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Termine (Date NOT NULL,Event NOT NULL, Date_String NOT NULL)");

    // prints the entire number of items from the database
    cur = db.executeQuery("select * from (select * from Termine order by Date) where Date >= 5;");

    // doesn't print anything
    cur = db.executeQuery("SELECT * from ( select m.*, Date r from Termine m ) where r > 4 and r < 10;");

    // doesn't print anything
    cur = db.executeQuery("SELECT * from ( select m.*, Date r from Termine m ) where r BETWEEN 5 AND 10;");

    while (cur.next()) {

        Row currentRow = cur.getRow();

        String event = currentRow.getString(1);

        System.out.println(event);

    }
```

Is my approach feasible? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `LIMIT` SQL keyword as explained [here](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-limit/).

```
SELECT column_list FROM table LIMIT row_count OFFSET offset;
```

A good practice is to search for "sqlite" and the SQL feature you are looking for as mobile SQL databases on all platforms are based on sqlite which has some quirks.

Comment: Great many thanks, Shai, easy solution and working perfectly.